# get values of data structure from arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an arraylist which has data structures in it.

I am having problems trying to figure out how to get those values back and show them in a table..

Thanks
this is my structure..

```
  public BackupSpecEntry(string Path, string InclExcl, byte InclExclFlags, bool IndexContents,
        int ServerBackupSpecId, int Freq, int Retention)
    {
        path = Path;
        inclExcl = InclExcl;
        inclExclFlags = InclExclFlags;
        indexContents = IndexContents;
        serverBackupSpecId = ServerBackupSpecId;
        freq = Freq;
        retention = Retention;
    }
```

Comment: It's a rather vague question. Can you show how you're "putting the structures" into the `ArrayList` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an ArrayList you need to cast them,

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayLIst();

: your code

BackupSpecEntry entry = (BackupSpecEntry)list[0];
```

However, with generics with C# you can create a template list:

```
List<BackupSpecEntry> list = new List<BackupSpecEntry>();

: your fill list code

BackupSpecEntry entry = list[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` isn't strongly typed so whenever you pull out an item, you have to cast it back to your custom object type.  Then you should be able to access it's properties.

Comment: could u give me an example... I am not able to follow...
Thanks for replying so fast..

Answer (score 0):

I assume by Table and by the Asp.net attribute that you mean a DataGrid, GridView, or DetailsView. Is this correct. Assuming that it is: read up on Data binding and custom objects. There is a lot of information about this subject on the internet if you look for it.